# 特定のアニメーションだけ無効化したい

Tags: javascript, css

ボタンをクリックしてダークモード化するスクリプトを作っています
枠線もボタンクリックで変化させたいですが、これだけアニメーションの時間をなくしたい（ぱっとすぐに切り替えるアニメーション方法にしたい）です

`transition: all 1s;`の下に`transition`を書いてみましたが、アニメーション全部が上書きされてしまいます
一つだけのアニメーションを変えることはできますか？

```js
$("#darkmode").on("click", function() {
  $("#message").toggleClass("alt")
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #000;
  padding: 20px;
}

#message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 1s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
}

button {
  background: #000;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#message.alt {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
}

#message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="message">
  <p>Hello, World</p>
  <button id="darkmode">Change darkmode</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`transition` プロパティは遷移を行う対象や効果を、カンマ区切りで複数指定することが出来ます<sup>[[1]](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transitions/#transition-shorthand-property)</sup>。そのため、 `all` キーワードで設定した遷移効果の後に、カンマ区切りで上書きしたい遷移対象を記述すれば良いことになります。

> #### § 2.5. The transition Shorthand Property<sup>[[1]](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transitions/#transition-shorthand-property)</sup>
>
> [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
#message {
  transition: all 1s, border;
}
```

```js
$("#darkmode").on("click", function() {
  $("#message").toggleClass("alt")
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #000;
  padding: 20px;
}

#message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 1s, border; /* 変更 */
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
}

button {
  background: #000;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#message.alt {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
}

#message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="message">
  <p>Hello, World</p>
  <button id="darkmode">Change darkmode</button>
</div>
```